# Blank result from mongodb find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I run the below query in mongo shell and get the desired results.

```
db.messagelist.find({userID : ObjectId("5e39a9c107357487435d5849")});
```

**Output**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39a9c1073574eb1a5d584a"), "message" : "I am at some place", "messageType" : "0", "messageLocation" : "0", "userID" : ObjectId("5e39a9c107357487435d5849"), "timeStamp" : "'1580837313163'" }
```

But when I create a route for it as follows, it returns blank results:

```
router.get('/messagelist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('messagelist');
    var id = req.params.id;
    //console.log("id is: "+id);
    //collection.find({userID : 'ObjectId("'+id+'")'});
    collection.find({"userID" : id}, {}, function (e, docs) {      
        docs = JSON.stringify(docs);
        console.log("docs: "+docs); //empty
        res.send(docs);         
    });
});
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax?! Any suggestions please.

**Edit:**

This query also works. So the syntax is correct in that case. I don't know what's the issue with userID.

```
router.get('/messagelist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('messagelist');
    var id = req.params.id;
    //console.log("id is: "+id);
    //db.messagelist.find({userID : 'ObjectId("'+id+'")'});

    collection.findOne({_id : id}, function(e, docs) {      
        console.log("docs: "+docs);
        docs = JSON.stringify(docs);
        console.log("docs: "+docs);
        res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

All the parameters are working except for the case of userID. It is weird. it is not even a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get('/messagelist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('messagelist');
    var id = req.params.id;
    //collection.find({userID : 'ObjectId("'+id+'")'});
    collection.find({"userID" : id}, {}, function (e, docs) {      
        docs = JSON.stringify(docs);
        res.send(docs);         
    });
});
```

The issue is that the representation of userID and the id (received from parameter) is not same.

**userID** is in the form:    **`ObjectId("5e3c13d7b5d89bc92c932243")`**

**id** is in the form:        **`"5e3c13d7b5d89bc92c930000"`**

And doing this, **'ObjectId("'+id+'")'** results in this:  **`"ObjectId(\"5e3c13d7b5d89bc92c930000\")"`**

So basically, **userID** could not match with **id** or **'ObjectId("'+id+'")'**

**Solution:**
I could not change the format in which the id is stored in any of the collections because of other dependencies.
So I created a separate referenceID (in the desired format) in messagelist-collection to store the objectIds of corresponding documents from the other collection.

```
router.get('/messagelist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('messagelist');
    var id = req.params.id;
    collection.findOne({refID: "'"+id+"'"}, {}, function(e, docs) {      
        docs = JSON.stringify(docs);
        res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using findOne method as it returns a single object/arbitrary document. If you're querying by _id (ducument id), use findById() instead.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Comment: Niether is working in the route. I get blank result. The find query takes conditions and outputs correctly in mongodb terminal. findOne() also works in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**find** method in Mongodb means **find all documents** so you don't need to pass a specific property to find what you want . Instead, use **findOne** and pass the property  or **findById** method and pass the id.

Comment: Niether is working in the route. I get blank result. The find query takes conditions and outputs correctly in mongodb terminal. findOne() also works in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
collection.find(id).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```